# How to force download for video (mp4) files on Nginx based on query parameter

Tags: nginx, video, download

I already got this working for images, but for unknown reasons it doesn't seem to work for video (mp4). I added the extension mp4, but it gets ignored.

My code;

```
location ~* ^/.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$ {
    autoindex off;
    if ($arg_dl = "1") {
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This may be the browser paying more attention to the `Content-Type` than the `Content-Disposition` header. You can set the `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` to force the browser to download the file.

The correct way to set the `Content-Type` is with the `types` and `default_type` directives. But these directives cannot appear within an `if` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) for details.

My workaround uses an internal URI prefix of `/download/` to implement the additional logic:

```
location ~* ^/.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$ {
    autoindex off;
    if ($arg_dl = "1") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /download$1 last;
    }
}
location ^~ /download {
    internal;
    alias /path/to/files;
    types {}
    expires -1;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
}
```