# nginx, why download on param query said me an error

Tags: nginx

here's my problem. I have added this code to my nginx.conf:

```
 location ~/.mp4 {
         if ($args_dl = "1") {
                types { application/octet-stream (.mp4); }
                default_type application/octet-stream;
         }
 }
```

When i restart nginx it said me

nginx: [emerg] "types" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26

Why? The line 26 is the `types { application/octet-stream (.mp4); }`

Thanks

EDIT: The true problem is: why if i add to the code `if ($args_dl = "1") {` nginx said me the error of "types"? I don't understand how it really works

RIEDIT: i think it's because i put type inside the if and it can't fit. How can I go about doing the same thing but without the if?

RIRIEDIT:

I have tried this:

```
    location ~* ^/.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$ {
    autoindex off;
    if ($arg_dl = "1") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /download$1 last;
    }
}
location ~ /download/.+\.(mp4) {
    internal;
    alias /home/$1;
    types {}
    expires -1;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
}
```

It doesn't work because i don't know how to set alias to dynamically take the url of the video and work with all different video i have and the browser gives me 500 internal server error when i change the url of the link in the location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types):

> Syntax:   types { ... }
>
> Context:  http, server, location

As you see there is no `if` in allowed contexts. In other words you can place `types` in `http`, `server`, or `location` block but not in `if` block.

Comment: how can i fix it? I need that functionality

Comment: @FounderOnepiecepower there is no fix for that. However, you can go from `$args_dl` to a different approach, i.e. you can make the thing to respond differently for `location ~ /play/.+\.mp4$` and `location ~ /download/.+\.mp4$`.

Comment: i have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745612/how-to-force-download-for-video-mp4-files-on-nginx-based-on-query-parameter but doesn't work to me. I don't know how to set alias dynamically in based of the link I give him. I update the question

Comment: @FounderOnepiecepower You can make several download locations to overcome the alias problem. E.g. `location ~ /download/.+\.(jpg|png|jpeg)` for images and `location ~ /download/.+\.(mp4)` for videos. This way you can a define different `alias` for each one.

Comment: the problem is that I have several videos. I tried alias /home/$1 but it still returns 404. How can I do that? Look at the code I updated at the beginning of the post

Comment: i set location to location ~ /download/.+\.(mp4) and now it said me 500 internal server error. Why?